# Morris JS Showing only Last data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, charts, morris.js

I am Trying to get the data dynamically from the Table in Morris Chart.
But the Problem is that its showing only the Single data from the Table which is the Last data .I am counting the data per month. but the data I am getting is the data of the last month

Here is the PHP Script Below :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT tots.*, @var := @var + tots.`count`
FROM (
    SELECT
       YEAR(created_at) AS `year`,
       MONTHNAME(created_at) AS `month`,
       COUNT(*) AS `count`
       FROM users
       GROUP BY `year`, `month`
     ) AS tots, (SELECT @var := 0) AS inc" ;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$chart_data = "{ month:'".$row["month"]."', count:".$row["count"]."}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2) ;
?>
```

And Here is my Morris JS Script :

```
<script>
Morris.Line({
element : 'chart',
data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
xkey:'month',
ykeys:['count'],
labels:['count'],
hideHover:'auto',
});
</script>
```

The Result I am getting is This.
[image]
 which is not Appropriate I want a line monthwise:

Comment: `$chart_data` always only have the value of the last row, that's why. Concat your value: `$chart_data .= "{ month:'".$row["month"]."', count:".$row["count"]."}, "`

Comment: doing this is giving me an error : Undefined variable: chart_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\linechart\index.php

Comment: define your variable before the while loop first `$chart_data = "";`

Comment: The error is gone . thanks for that. but I am still not able to get the result in the graph

Comment: Here is the updated code : 

    $chart_data = "" ;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {

    $chart_data .= "{ month:'".$row["month"]."', count:".$row["count"]."}, ";
    }
    $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2) ;

Comment: Debug: 1) check how many rows the SQL command output. 2> check $chart_data has a valid JSON format 3) open browser console, see is there any error?

Comment: If only chartdata was chartdata[]

Answer (score 0):

Seems the label are too long. You can try with shorter label, like `Jan-19` instead of `January 2019`.